# How to force rotation of a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I've a `UINavigationController` wich contains some `UIViewController`... All those `UIVienController` should be only in **Portrait** mode.

But in only one of those `UIViewController`, I should `presentModalViewController`. This `modalViewController` should be allowed to rotate in all orientation.
No problem until I want to dismiss this `modalViewController`.

If this `modalViewController` was in **Landscape** mode when I dismiss it. The `parentViewController` don't get back to Portrait.

How can I force the rotation of my `parentViewController`? I tried some solution but I can't make it to work. Any suggestion ?

Comment: what exactly did you try?

Comment: I trying to allow only ONE UIViewController to all orientation, and this UIViewController should be presented as modal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are presenting your `modalviewcontroller` with `presentModalViewController` when you dismiss `modalviewcontroller`, `viewWillApper` or `viewDIdAppear` methods wont get called.

You have to call methods in your `UIViewController` via `nsnotifcation` or `delegate pattern`.

So when you dismiss `modalviewcontroller` notify your `UIViewController` and call `yourmethod` in `yourmethod` detect current orientation and if its not portrait change it to portrait.

```
-(void) yourmethod 
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight )
    {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    } 

}
```

Comment: viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear is called after a dismiss... and setting the statusBar orientation to portrait does only put the statusBar in portrait mode, not all the viewController.

Comment: that means you are using previous versions of IOS 5- , because in IOS 5 and later viewWillAppear wont get called when you dismiss a modalview.

Comment: viewWillAppear is called in the RootViewController if I dismiss my ModalViewController, plz check what you say. I'm on iOS6 like you and it works... I just tested it.